# Rechecking column row value every few seconds to conditionally perform an action

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, vbscript

There are certain column rows in my MSSQL database's table that I need to keep checking continuously after the page loads to see whether the bit value is False or True. I'm using ASPX pages and VB code files.

I've tried using a While loop with three second Sleep intervals though doesn't work. What should I be doing to accomplish this rechecking of the column row value every 3 seconds?

```
ds = dataFetcher.fillDataset("Procedure1 '" & id & "'", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyString").ConnectionString, False)
While 1
   If ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("machine_ready") = True Then
       Response.Redirect("machines.aspx") 'Do this when machine is ready
   End If
   Thread.Sleep(3000) 'Wait three seconds
End While
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work, what happens?

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a timer in JS code and making an AJAX call.

Comment: @jmcilhinney That means I would need to connect to db using JS code?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Why can't I just use VB?

Comment: VB code is executed on the server.  The user views a page in their browser and makes a request to the server.  The server processes that request and then returns a page to the browser.  If your VB code executed on the server takes a long time then the user will not see anything returned to the browser for a long time.  Once a page is returned to the browser, there is no VB code running on the server any longer.  Web apps are not like Windows apps, where the whole thing is running in front of the user at all times.  In a web app, a timer meeds to run on the client, i.e. in the browser.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Can I use an ASP UpdatePanel and Timer? Or, does it have to be "JS code and making an AJAX call"? Very unfamilar with JS code and making an AJAX call compared to VB.

Comment: Using an `UpdatePanel` actually is using JavaScript and AJAX.  It's just wrapped up in VB code so that it's easier.  In short, yes you can.